# React setState and update() addon

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm a beginer using ReactJS and today I had a situation that I don't know how to be explain.

I'm working on a project with a similar situation as described bellow:

```js
      var update = React.addons.update;

      
      class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
           this.state = {
             group1: 'show',
             group2: 'A'
          };
          this.Update = this.Update.bind(this);
          this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
        }
        
        Update(e, value = ''){
          let field = e;

          if(!value) field = e.target.name

          //this solution work
          /*this.setState({
            [field]: value || e.target.value
          });*/

          
            
          //this solution doesn't work
          let theState = Object.assign({}, this.state),
              updatedState = update(theState,{[field]: {$set: value || e.target.value}})
          console.log("UPDATE RESULTS");console.log(updatedState);
          this.setState(updatedState);
        }
          
        
 handleChange1(e) {
          const filters = this.state
          if(filters.group1 === 'show' && filters.group2 === 'C' ){
            this.Update('group2', 'A');
          }
          this.Update(e);
        }

        render() { 
            const filters = this.state;
            console.log("RENDER");console.log(filters);
            return (
              <div className="widget">
               <div>
                  Group 1<br />
                  <input type="radio" value="show" name="group1"  defaultChecked={filters.group1 === 'show'} onChange={this.handleChange1} /> Show All Group 2 
                  <input type="radio" value="hide" name="group1"  defaultChecked={filters.group1 === 'hide'} onChange={this.handleChange1} /> Hide 3rd option
                </div>
                <br /><br />
              
                <div>
                  Group 2<br />
                  <input type="radio" value="A" name="group2"  checked={filters.group2 === 'A'} onChange={this.Update} /> A
                  <input type="radio" value="B" name="group2"  checked={filters.group2 === 'B'} onChange={this.Update} /> B
                  {filters.group1 === 'show' && <label><input type="radio" value="C" name="group2"  checked={filters.group2 === 'C'} onChange={this.Update} /> C</label>}
                </div>
             </div>
           );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<HelloWidget />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.widget {
    width: 402px;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Shortly, I have a function that update state from different children Components. According attached source code, changing options in first radio group should show or hide an option (last) on second radio group. If the hidden option is checked then default (first) option should been checked after hide.

Everything works fine when I use setState() directly, but because of state object complexity, I used [update() addon](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) and the result is not the same - default option on second radio group is not checked after last is hidden.

Where is my issue using update()?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the results of your `update(...)` call?  How does that compare with the "solution that works" ?

Comment: Unless you are using React v0.13.1 intentionally, you should likely update (the latest is [v15.5.4](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react)), which you can do by simply changing the version number in your cdnjs url

Comment: The version no mater in this case, the result is the same

Comment: What is different (and maybe the reason?) is that using setState directly I updated just one field of state object, but using update() I sent to update entire state object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is what is sent to update: for working solution  - just one field, using update() - entire state object.

If I will change the working part to :

```
          let theState = Object.assign({}, this.state),
              updatedState = Object.assign({}, theState, {
                [field]: value || e.target.value
              })
          ;

          this.setState(updatedState);
```

then I will receive the same issue.